# Coloring only the median in the boxplot

Tags: r, colors, boxplot

Is there a way to color only the median line of the boxplot and not the whole boxplot.

When I try this :

```
boxplot(matrix,col="red")
```

then the whole box gets red colored.
I want to color only the median line of the boxplot.

Is there a way to do it in R ??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `medcol` as in

```
boxplot(matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=2), medcol="red")
```

[image]