# ggplot - make the median invisible geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

for some obscure reason, I must draw a boxplot with no apparent median. How can I achieve this (using `ggplot` is preferred, but if it is necessary I will switch to `boxplot`) please?

Related answers:

- use `fatten` parameter: I tried setting the fatten parameter to 0,
  following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475865/change-thickness-median-line-geom-boxplot) answer. A thin line remains.
- use `geom_segment` : I tried to superpose a white segment onto the median using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002257/change-color-median-line-ggplot-geom-boxplot) method. But superposing a white segment onto the median line is unsatisfactory because the edges of the box are also erased. I think this approach would work using `boxplot` though, since, as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071371/coloring-only-the-median-in-the-boxplot) it is possible to change the median's color without affecting the edges of the box.

Comment: `flatten = 0` works for me, `packageVersion('ggplot2') # [1] ‘2.2.1’`

Comment: You could also try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30002461/3198540)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One kind of "hacky" way to do this would be use the `fatten` argument in the answer you posted, but set it equal to `NULL`. Note since you didn't post any data, I used `mtcars` a built in R dataset. This would look like:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = mtcars) + geom_boxplot(aes(x = as.factor(am), y = hp), fatten = NULL)
```

[image]